# AppInventor - Three values in one row list

Tags: app-inventor

I would like to insert into my TinyDB values like: current_address, current_latitude, current_longitude
I've created something like this:
[image]
https://gyazo.com/4a63791c17182838841d5b6e78b6359b

But it shows values like:
`Current address`
in next row `latitude`
in next row `longitude`

I would like to have everything in one row like:

```
address. latitude, longitude
```

Comment: Use a join block to create a single list item of all three pieces of data, or use the join items with separator list block, to join them from your list to send to the listview

Answer (score 1):

Use a join block and instead of putting it on a list view, put it in a label:

[image: Code]